# Running parallel count query with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, task-parallel-library

I have a search functionality that needs to show the user a summary of the search for several categories, and right now, what its done is one query at a time, one for the search itself and one for each summary (group by queries). The end result is a page that shows the search result and a right column with a summary like states where the items are available with its count, colors, sizes etc.

As I said, these queries are done one by one and what I want to do is group all of theses summary queries and execute them using the `Parallel.Invoke` method and leave only the query that return the search result itself out of this parallel method.

What I want to do is get some performance as all of these queries do are count data, it doesn't make any update to the database.

Would that work? If not, what would be the best solution? I'm using dependency injection and I think that a design change to create a new DbContext for each query would be a lot of change...

Comment: What vershio of ASP.NET MVC and EF do you use? You can go with async approach or with Task.Run

Comment: I'm using MVC 5 with .net 4.5.2 and EF 6.1.1. How would that be?

Answer (score 3):

This will not work because DbContext is [not guaranteed to be thread-safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#threadSafetyToggle). This effectively means that even read-only queries that do not affect DB state, can run you into concurrency issues.

You will need to have separate DbContext instance for each parallel query.

Another solution to this would be to create a View in the database that will "calculate" needed results.